# Splitting out product details in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet full of product details that have been scraped from a website. All the dimensions are grouped in one cell by product. The same goes for product details. Some contain more dimension and product details than others.

[image]

Is there a way to split all these out into unique columns?

Thanks!

Comment: here is a blank anonymous spreadsheet created specifically to answer this question.  if you paste some sample data there, it will be easier to demonstrate how to do it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OftektPONV2q9u5ylSGLXW5ZOXVe17cuyicyD-aFwmE/edit

Comment: Can you share how are you getting the information, are you already using apps script to populate the sheet?

Comment: @MattKing I've added a sample bit of data in there for you.

Comment: @Kessy - I'm not using a script to pull the data, it's all being scraped by an another piece of software which spits out a csv file in this format.

Comment: There does not seem to be consistency on the line breaks or character delimiters in column F.   Lines 13 and 14 are very different from the first 11.   Not sure it will be possible without more consistency in that column.

Answer (score 1):

Any cell that contains multiple lines of text can be split into an array of text.  For example G112 contains 7 lines.

```
function test() {
  try {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var value = sh.getRange("G112").getValue();
    console.log(value.split('\n'));
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Would produce an array ['Size Small','Item Width 1,400mm',...]?

Since each cell has a different number of lines you'll have to pack some rows to make a symmetrical 2 dimensional array and then put if back somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Ed. How do I get that script to output the array?

Comment: See this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)